# vue-router neither watch route or navigation guards firing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Using vue-router in a single page application with the code below, the watch $route function in not firing when redirecting to mycomponent.

Also the beforeRouteUpdate in mycomponent is also not firing.

How can I detect when a variable has been tagged on to a route during component load?

App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import MyView from '@/views/MyView'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/mycomponent',
          name: 'MyComponent',
          component: MyComponentView
        },
        {
          path: '/mycomponent/:id',
          component: MyComponentView,
          props: true
        }
]}]})
```

mycomponent.vue

```
<template>
  <component :is="activeComponent" :id="id"></component>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponentView',
    components: {
      ...
    },
    mounted: function() {
      #this logs path in browser
      console.log('>>mounted route: ' + this.$route.path)
    },
    watch: {
      '$route': function () {
        #this does not fire
        console.log('route watcher: ' + this.$route.path)
      }
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
      #this does not fire
      console.log('>>beforeRouteUpdate')
    },
    data () {
      return {
        activeComponent: 'somecomponent'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

component1.vue

```
...
mounted: function() {
  Event.$on('vue-tables.row-click', function(data) {
    #this logs correct information in browser
    console.log('data.row.id: ' + data.row.id)
    router.push({path: 'mycomponent', query: {id: data.row.id}})
  })
},
...
```

Comment: Are you certain your dynamic components are working?

Comment: The redicection to mycomponent works, and the mounted function works fine, just not the watch or beforerouteUpdate functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work because `beforeRouteUpdate` is in component which is going to reload (Look at Life cycle of Vue). When you change the route, `watch` & `beforeRouteUpdate` is terminated and you won't see any results. In this scenario you should provide something like this:

### MainRouterView.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
  name: 'MainRouterView',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    console.log('beforeRouteUpdate')
  },
</script>
```

### router.js

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
        {
          path: '/mycomponent',
          name: 'MainRouterView',
          component: MainRouterView,
          children: [
            {
              path: '/mycomponent/:id',
              component: SecondComponent,
            }
          ]
        },
      }]})
```

But if you want to stick up with your structure and check the status of the current route, you can replace `beforeRouteUpdate` to `beforeRouteEnter` or `beforeRouteLeave` in the component. You can use global guard `beforeEach` in router as well.

To better understand how `beforeRouteUpdate` works, check out this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/yraqs4cb/